# Primefaces Download File Which is Outside FacesContext

Tags: java, excel, jsf-2, primefaces, download

I'm uploading an Excel Workbook to a directory which is outside the application context (for backup purposes) and saving its path into the database.

Now I need to download that file and I'm trying to use Primefaces Download, but I'm getting a **null file**.

Here is my code (much like Primefaces Showcase Download section):

Bean:

```
private StreamedContent file;

public void download(Arquivo arquivo) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
      .getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream(arquivo.getNomeArquivo());

    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream);
}
```

View:

```
<h:commandLink id="btnDownload" title="Download Arquivo" 
  actionListener="#{arquivoBean.download(obj)}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{arquivoBean.file}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Basically I need to pass an external path to InputStream instead of FacesContext.

From what I see my problem is that I'm passing my application context to the InputStream, appending the path in the argument of getResourceAsStream which, of course, is not found.

I'm new to this FileDownload thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just create a file input stream based on the path..? Accessing the local disk file system is not different in a JSF backing bean class than in a regular Java application class. Neither JSF nor `<p:fileDownload>` cares how exactly you create the `InputStream` instance, as long as it's an instance of `InputStream`.

Comment: I tried doing this:
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(arquivo.getNomeArquivo());
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream);

But now I get a null.txt file.

Comment: So the file contents is all fine and only the file name not? You indeed didn't specify the file name anywhere in `DefaultStreamedContent`. You only specified the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

If it can still be useful :

```
StreamedContent streamToReturn = DefaultStreamedContent.builder().name(FILE_NAME).contentType( FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getMimeType(FILE_PATH))
            .stream(() -> {
                try {
                    return new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }).build();
```