# Using PrimeFaces StreamedContent for FileDownload from different new context requires absolute file system path

Tags: tomcat, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces FileDownload

http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml?jfwid=5e94c

My application allows users to provide file downloads for their customers. User uploaded files are stored in a different context "media" which is added in Tomcat's server.xml

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/media" path="/media" />
```

PrimeFaces download.xthml

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
function start() {
    PF('statusDialog').show();
}

function stop() {
    PF('statusDialog').hide();
}
//]]>
```

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);"
                     icon="pi pi-arrow-down" styleClass="mr-2">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}"/>
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:commandButton value="Ajax Download" icon="pi pi-arrow-down" styleClass="ui-button-outlined">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The PrimeFaces backing bean is posted as:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class FileDownloadView {

    private StreamedContent file;

    public FileDownloadView() {
        file = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                .name("downloaded_boromir.jpg")
                .contentType("image/jpg")
                .stream(() -> FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/demo/images/boromir.jpg"))
                .build();
    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }
}
```

Note that in the PF sample code, the file "boromir.jpg" is located in the directory designated as a Web Content resources directory.

```
String absolutePath1 = "/media/path/to/file";
String absolutePath2 = "/path/to/media/path/to/file";
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(absolutePath1) and
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(absolutePath2)
```

both result in a NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.InputStream.read(byte[])" because "input" is null
```

I was able to successfully get FileDownload to download files by modifying FileDownloadView as FileDownloadBean. This required explicitly declaring the InputStream using the full absolute file system path.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestFileDownloadBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private StreamedContent _testFileDownload;
    
    public TestFileDownloadBean()
    {
        String absoluteSystemPath = "/full/path/to/media/sampleDownload.pdf";
        try
        {
            File file = new File(absolutePath);
            InputStream inputStream =
                    new FileInputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            _testFileDownload =
                    DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                    .name("sample_pdf.pdf")
                    .contentType("application/pdf")
                    .stream(() -> inputStream)
                    .build();   
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    
    public StreamedContent getTestFileDownload()
    {
        return _testFileDownload;
    }

    public void setTestFileDownload(StreamedContent testFileDownload)
    {
        _testFileDownload = testFileDownload;
    }
}
```

My question: Surely there is another way to do this using path beginning with "/media/"?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think so.  Because PrimeFaces has not idea about Tomcat OR its Media directory you have to provide the fully qualified path how to find the file on the OS file system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Primefaces Download File Which is Outside FacesContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194931/primefaces-download-file-which-is-outside-facescontext)

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your response.